# vim c++ configuration

Tags: c++, vim

I am a newbie in vim. I want to use it as C++ IDE or something like this. I already install these plugins:

- [c.vim : C/C++ IDE](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213)
- [project.tar.gz : Organize/Navigate projects
  of files](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=69)

But I still cannot use them there is different errors or issues. Also I have a lot of questions how to configure vim to run/build/debug c++ code, for example with cmake, how to make it quick and professional with debug/release configuration separately. Can any sophisticated c++ vim programmers show me what do they use and with which configurations and at which point of their configuration I should pay attention?

Thanks.

I think zir archive with vim would be good to learn this stuff.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @honk Can any sophisticated c++ vim programmers show me what do they use for c++ vim programming? List the plugins what are u using. List any personal or important settings what did you make to use vim for c++? And I be grateful if you upload you all your vim editor with all your configurations and other stuff which you suppose is important and helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Your current question has no right answer so it will likely be closed. I use a, alternate, surround, tabular, ctags integration and clang complete.  For everything else there are Makefiles and `:make` (but that might be my opinion only).

Comment: Year it is great! I want at least one full personal opinion of professional c++ vim programmer than I assign it like a right answer. Please make an answer with more details which you suppose is important and upload a zip archive of your vim editor with all your configurations and other stuff which you suppose is important and helpful.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/faq for what is on topic here and review your question.

Comment: itun, regarding your question "Can any sophisticated c++ vim programmers...", check my (old) answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623605/c-vim-ide-things-youd-need-from-it and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149558/recommended-vim-plugins-for-c-coding/152448#152448 (sorry I use neither c.vim nor project.vim)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the most important IDE's features are:

- Editing
- Searching
- Tags ("Goto Definition" in Visual Studio)
- Source Control Integration
- Building
- Debugging

Emacs has typically tried to accomplish all of these things and more (including running a shell inside Emacs).  Vi has typically been more lightweight but has gotten more functionality since the advent of Vim.  I have not seriously tried to use Vim for building or debugging -- I find it difficult when I go to new projects that are using different build and debug environments.

However, there are many things that I do to integrate Vim with various IDE's and stay in Vim as much as possible.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8897164/1113528 for Tags, Source Control Integration, Clipboard, IDE integration (ability to jump to build errors).  I also have a custom search plugin -- I think you would be better off looking for a more standard search vim plugin.

In order to switch between Visual Studio, Eclipse and Vim, I setup external spawning of Vim for <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd>.  To set this up, do the following:

## Visual Studio

1. Tools | External Tools | Add
2. Title:`Vim` | Command:`C:\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe` | Arguments:`--servername ext --remote-silent +$(CurLine) $(ItemPath)`
3. Move up to first position
4. Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard
5. Show commands containing: Tools.ExternalCommand1
6. Press shortcut keys: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd>
7. Apply, OK

## Eclipse

1. Run | External Tools | External Tool Configurations
2. Location: `C:\Vim\vim73\gvim.exe`
3. Arguments: `--servername ext --remote-silent ${resource_loc}`
4. Window | Preferences | General | Keys
5. Filter `Run Last`
6. Binding <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd>
7. Apply, OK